Should I cache and re-use a `MTKMeshBufferAllocator`?
Every piece of Metal example code, both from Apple and 3rd-party, seems to re-allocate a MTKMeshBufferAllocator every time they need one.  It's a reference type, and rarely does the MTLDevice used to create it change, so this pattern confuses me.  Apple documentation provides no hints.
Is this usage intentional, and caching MTKMeshBufferAllocator is bad?
Or, is it just to keep sample code simple, and caching MTKMeshBufferAllocator is fine, so long as you re-create it if your MTLDevice changes?
(Using a cached MTKMeshBufferAllocator causes no immediately apparent issues.)
